# Translate WordPress plugin header

Tags: php, wordpress, translation

How can I translate WordPress plug-in header?

I have translate all strings in my plug-in using:

1. `__()` and `_e()` functions
2. .po files
3. Text Domain
4. WordPress function to load language file

   ```
   load_plugin_textdomain('mnbaa-seo', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
   ```

I want to translate this section

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Mnbaa SEO
Plugin URI: http://www.mnbaa.com
Description: WP blugin fom make SEO and Social SEO.
Author: Mnbaa CO
Author URI: http://www.mnbaa.com
Version: 1.0
Text Domian:mnbaa-seo
Domain Path: /languages/
*/
?>
```

Comment: I doubt it is possible to automatically translate this using the functions.

Comment: I have tried it but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use WordPress' [i18n tools](https://github.com/wp-mirrors/wp-i18n-tools) to get the plugin's description translatable. i18n tools' makepot.php lets you auto-generate a .pot file, which then can be used to create the .mo/.po pair (with the free [PoEdit](https://poedit.net/) for example).

The easiest way would be:

1. Download the [zip](https://github.com/wp-mirrors/wp-i18n-tools/archive/master.zip) from https://github.com/wp-mirrors/wp-i18n-tools.
2. Extract its content into the wp-includes folder.
3. Command line one-liner from within WP root: `$ php wp-includes/makepot.php wp-plugin wp-content/plugins/MYPLUGIN/ wp-content/plugins/MYPLUGIN/MYLANGFOLDER/MYPLUGIN.pot`
4. Then you take this resulting .pot file as source for PoEdit.
5. Finally ensure to name the .mo/.po like your plugin plus language code, for example: MYPLUGIN-de_DE.mo/MYPLUGIN-de_DE.po.

More (but not quite up-to-date) info can be found at WPO: https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Translating_Plugins_and_Themes

I wonder if maybe PoEdit Pro can do that without us calling on the command line... Maybe someone who knows can drop a comment below.

Comment: I use PoEdit Pro and it does the job perfectly. Doesn't need any coding or crazy settings. It's a piece of cake!

Comment: i tried, everything is working fine, can you please suggest how can i translate the /* description : this is my plugin description */

Comment: @AwsmeSandy - I'ld suggest you follow the steps 1. - 5. from above or you buy PoEdit Pro.

Comment: I tried the same and getting `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp64\www\plugintester\testrelarticles\wp-includes\extract\extract.php on line 25` error

Answer (score -1):

Add somewhere inside your plugin code a dummy translation for the description and plugin name:

```
$dummy_name = __( 'Mnbaa SEO', 'mnbaa-seo' );
$dummy_desc = __( 'WP blugin fom make SEO and Social SEO.', 'mnbaa-seo' );
```

Then re-generate the `.po`/`.mo` pair.

I use only `/languages` for `Domain Path`, no trailing slash.
Check [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/752/12615) for I18n support by plugins.