# how do I change the font of a button when the language of the website changes

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The website I want to edit runs with Wordpress. There is a button on the homepage with which you can change the language. Then you are in: [www.xy.com/de/](http://www.xy.com/de/). The endings change the url are different for different languages. Also the whole website is translated only one button in the header is not translated. How can I set that it will be changed with when I change to the respective language.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Translate WordPress plugin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739544/translate-wordpress-plugin-header)

Comment: Is the translation being provided by a Wordpress plugin? If so, which one?